# failing to upload image files to my django database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django Framework, I have created a html form to upload Post title, description and Image.

Image is not uploading to the database. Please look into the code and suggest me how to fix this.

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics_post')
    desc = models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
def index (request) :

    posts = Post.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST' :

        if request.POST.get('newpost') == 'Submit':

            # post_title = request.POST.get('posttitle')
            # post_desc = request.POST.get('post_desc')
            # post_image = request.FILES['post_img']
            # post = Post(title = post_title, desc = post_desc, img = post_image)
            # post.save()
            # return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts' : posts})

            formdata = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

            if formdata.is_valid():
                formdata.save()
                return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts' : posts})
            else :
                pass
                return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts' : posts})

        else : pass
    else : 
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts' : posts})
```

HTML form

```
<form action="#" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control newpost" name="posttitle" placeholder="Post Title" id="posttitle" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control newpost" name="post_desc" placeholder="Post Description" id="postdesc" required size="100" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" class="newpost" name="post_img" id="postimage" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
                            <p class="form-text text-muted">Only png and jpg allowed</p>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name='newpost' id="commentsubmit" style="float: right;" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

The commented part in the views.py is what i was trying, and failed miserably.
Then i tried to add the forms.py and failed with that too.

Comment: did you add your media root to settings & url?

Comment: @Jay i added enctype="multipart/form-data" this in the html, and updated the project settings, and i am able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Your html form should be,

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```